# Can we have multiple GitHub Pages sites for a single repository?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a main folder "10Hour10Project", which is uploaded on GitHub as a repository, inside that folder I have 10 mini projects. Is it possible that I get a different GitHub Pages link for each of my mini projects inside that repo?

Comment: No, you only get one pages site (`<user>.github.io/<repo>`) per repo. Maybe you could make them different pages (`<user>.github.io/<repo>/<project>`) within that?